# rest client vscode extention is not sending json data

Tags: node.js, json, visual-studio-code, http-post

I am using REST client extension of vscode instead of postman because of lightweight but it seems it's not sending JSON data when I try to send POST requests. it's working fine on postman and reqbin but not with the REST client I just receive the empty body.

here is the request URL

```
@hostname-tour = http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tours 

POST {{hostname-tour}} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: "application/json" 

{
    "name": "Test Tour",
    "duration": "10",
    "diffculty": "easy"
}
```

here is backend code

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/api/v1/tours", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  res.status(200).json({
    received: req.body,
  });
});

let port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Listening at port: ", port);
});
```

all working fine with Postman and reqbin
[image: reqbin output]

but receiving empty object from REST client
[image: Rest Client extension output]

Answer (score 7):

Problem here

```
Content-Type: "application/json"
```

change to

```
content-type: application/json
```

Comment: i changed but it didnt resolve same empty object

Comment: it works on my side. Remember save changes before send the request

Comment: yes i did the same as you said and saved. but didn't work. if you have time can you come to anydesk?

Comment: @MubasherAli I don't know. see this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1483gDtQpuCYPRdbXwZkjlwCC4Xqwj4Pg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ohhh i found the solution it was with the quotes. i was using quotes in "application/json"

Comment: If you have an empty line between the REST URL and content-type, please remove.. this won't work in my case

Answer (score 0):

just remove the quotes from *"application/json"* as shown below

```js
@hostname-tour = http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tours 

POST {{hostname-tour}} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Test Tour",
    "duration": "10",
    "diffculty": "easy"
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I had removed the quotes. Everything was OK. The problem turned out to be that the API was returning a bad response when receiving a JSON body. It was a endpoint problem and not the plugin not working properly. I deleted my previous message. Thanks :)